# Submission form : On Enter key press cancel action is being called

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a submission form with Cancel and Submit button. Once input field is focused and Enter key is pressed then function on Cancel button is invoked. However it should invoke the function on Submit button with type="submit". Also I cannot change the DOM structure. Any tips

```
<form>
<input id="title" type="text"/>
<button onClick={()=>{console.log("cancel")}>Cancel</button>
<button type="submit" onClick={()=>{console.log("submit")}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Your first button _is_ a submit button, because that is the implicit default for the `type` attribute. And hitting [enter] while the focus is in the single text field of a form, will automatically activate the “default” submit button, which is the first one found in DOM order.

Comment: Thankyou for your explanation. I have explicitly changed the `type` of  `Cancel` button and it worked  `<button type="button" onClick={()=>{console.log("cancel")}>Cancel</button>`